# Radare2 and Boomerang

Tags: radare2

I found [this](http://radare.org/doc/html/Section22.9.html) post stating that Radare can work with [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/). However when I try do exactly as they say, I get the following error: `sh: 1: rsc: not found`.

From what I can see, `rsc` is an extra utility that would have come in with Radare1. See [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/rsc.1.html).

I understand that ! causes Radare to execute a shell command so I therefore need the `rsc` utility. However I cannot find it anywhere!

I'm using Radare2 0.10.0 compiled from git and Boomerang compiled from git as well.

Does anyone know what the state of these two tools working together is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello o/ this is the radare1book concerning radare1, use the [radare2book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/) for radare2. Boomerang hasn't been yet added to r2 in this version, you can use `pdc` and [retdec](https://asciinema.org/a/20904) (see r2pm). We are actually working on [radeco](https://github.com/radare/radeco). But you can always contribute and maybe add back this support to r2 ? That would be interesting

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per your advice I have just setup retdec with radare2! It works fantastic. Keep up the great work!